# Is it possible to run html forms on android via a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I just recently started to try Google Spreadsheet and Apps Scripts as an alternative for Excel and VBA for some tasks which require multiple users to work together. I created some html forms and everything works fine on the PC so far, but I questionend myself if there is a possibility to run html forms on mobile devices/Android. On my research i found no possibility to view my created menu on android but it's possible to create a "menu" with a dropdown list where the input runs script functions through the onEdit()-function. This works for script funcitons, but so far I failed to call a html form this way. Is there a possibility to make it happen or other alternatives to use userforms/userinterfaces on android?

Here is my code for to run the script functions via a dropdown list. In my first sheet is a dropdown list in B1 with the following three entries: insertSomething, convertSomething and runHTML. the entries have the identical name as my script functions and the first and second function runs without problems, but i can't run the html form. Is there a way to make it work?

```js
    function onEdit(e) {
      if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B1') {
        if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
          eval(e.value)();
          e.range.clear();
        }
      }
    }

    function insertSomething() { 
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange(2,3).setValue('inserted something');
    }  

    function convertSomething() { 
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange(3,3).setValue('converted something');
    }  

    function runHTML() {
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('runHTML');
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
          .showModalDialog(html, 'runHTML');
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, World!
    <input type="button" value="Close"
        onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

I appreciate your help :)

Comment: How are you opening the sheet in your mobile ?

Comment: The google spreadsheet app. But it also doens't work using my PC to run the third function (runHTML).

Comment: For me its working, how are you trying to run ? Dropdown is having function names, fine. How are you triggering the functions?

Comment: @Umair: you select a data via the dropdown and the OnEdit-Function calls the seleted function (name of the seleted data = function name). Each function for itself works, but not as a combination with the dropdown menu.

Comment: @I'-'I: I feared html doesn't run on android. So I will try to run it all via app scripts, despite forms via App Scripts being deprecated ^^

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service

Comment: Btw the trigger via dropdown is from a user here on stackoverflow. If I find the respective link I'll post it, because credit were credit is due the solution is indeed ingenious.